# Phases of the moon video

Tags: astronomy, specific-reference, education, moon

I am an educator, and I am looking for a specific video.  In the video, they ask some middle school students and some college graduates about why the moon has phases.  Most of the students in both the groups get the answer wrong, saying that the phases of the moon happen because of the shadow of the Earth.  I remember that they also interviewed the teacher of the middle school students, and she was really perplexed that her students didn't know the right answer.

Another thing I remember from the video was that the middle school kids were not sure of their answers, but the college graduates (who are at their graduation ceremony) were really sure.

I want to use that video for educational purposes, but I can't find it.  Can you please help?

Comment: Are you sure it's phases of the moon?  I've seen one like that that is about the seasons, where they're asking Harvard graduates on graduation day and like 1 in 10 know why we have seasons.

Comment: Thank you!  That is why I couldn't find it till now.  For those interested: http://www.learner.org/resources/series28.html has the video.

Answer (score 2):

This video seems to have been made for kids:  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sXK63GpwUqs  Does that help?

Comment: This is a link-only answer, which is generally not good for Stack Exchange. Can you explain the material in the link? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to video on the Phases of the Moon
https://youtu.be/NCweccNOaqo

Similar videos are linked to it.

Comment: This does not seem to be the video that the OP was asking for.